# How to call a function from Props interface in Typescript/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I'm trying to update the state of a parent component from the child. I've passed down a function in the Props interfact, but I can't seem to call it using my clickHandler.

There's user info in the parent component which should update from various small components that comprise a registration.

Does this seem to be the right approach?

**App.tsx**

```
  const updateName = (
        e: React.MouseEvent,     // Function to update parent state
        firstName: string,       // Triggered by child components
        lastName: string
    ) => {
        setFirstName(firstName);
        setLastName(lastName);
    };
```

Component render with this function as prop:

```
  <FullName
      firstName={""}
      lastName={""}
      updateName={(e, first: string, last: string) =>
          updateName(e, first, last)
      }
  />;
```

**inside ChildComponent.tsx**

This is the props interface:

```
interface NameProps {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    updateName: (e: React.MouseEvent, first: string, last: string) => void;
}
```

This is where I want to call the function, in order to send the state data from the child, to the parent as an argument in updateName!

```
    function handleClick(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
        console.log(first, last);

        // I want to call NameProps.updateName here

    }
```

Please let me know if this is totally the wrong approach, but it seems I'm very close.

Answer (score 0):

So what stops you from calling the updateName() from child? Can you paste your child component's code? Is it a class or functional component?

I do this like this:

In Parent:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const myFunction = function (someArgument) {
    // do stuff
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <Child stringParameter="foo" myFunction={myFunction}/>
  </div>
  );
};
```

In child:

```
const Child = ( { stringParameter, myFunction} ) => {
  myFunction(stringParameter);

  return (
    <div>lorem ipsum</div>
  );
};
```

I've made it as simple as possible so I hope this answers your question (no interface etc.). Of course props deconstruction also for readability.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I solved the problem in the end. It was a matter of specifying which props I was including as an argument. Have updated the question :)